# Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS dat=package:com.example.batterop }

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activitynotfoundexception

```
when run this code that exception throw 
Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);  //intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);  //intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
```

//intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);    intent.setData(uri);  startActivity(intent);  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  startActivity(intent);

```
2022-03-08 22:55:45.172 3715-3715/com.example.batterop E/Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS dat=package:com.example.batterop }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in the **Manifest** file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

In Kotlin use like this:

```
  @SuppressLint("BatteryLife")
    fun permissionBattery() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            val packageName: String = baseContext.packageName
            val pm: PowerManager =
                baseContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
            if (!pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                intent.data = Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
                baseContext.startActivity(intent)
            }

        }


    }
```